# How to perform operation on a grouped data set and replace the corresponding values in original df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a given dataframe, I need to group the data (via groupby) and perform an operation on the grouped data (eg: grouped_data - 100). After this, I need to replace the old values in the dataframe with the new values I just calculated.

I have tried assigning the obtained values to the grouped data frame, but it does not seem to work.

Grouped Dataframe

```
       altitude_feet    Column_irrelevant_A     Column_irrelevant_B     
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN           
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN
     1889.155095                NaN                    NaN

    new_values= (df.groupby('columnA').get_group(101)['altitude_feet'])-100
    df.groupby('coulmnA').get_group(101)['altitude_feet'] = new_values
```

I wish to subtract 100ft from the above and store that as the new altitude_feet in the initial dataframe prior to grouping

I expect to approxiamtely 1789 for the altitude

I have also considered avoiding grouping and simply finding the index instead

```
data[data['columnA']==101].assign(...)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

just define a function and use apply(). I used an example dataset from seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df=sns.load_dataset('iris')
def f(grp):
    dfx=grp.copy()
    dfx['new_sepal_length']=dfx.sepal_length-100
    return dfx

df_new=df.groupby('species').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Instead of df, I created the new dataframe df_new so you can compare df with df_new.